# Selenium can not find an element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Actually my code is simple and the task too, but somehow i get this Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"TLoginBox"}
```

I tried any of the find element and find element by options but none did work.
All i found out is that on the website where the login button is, that the button itself somehow is a whole HTML with head, body,...

[T-online Email Link](https://www.t-online.de/themen/e-mail)

That's my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Chrome('F:/trzttrtz/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.t-online.de/themen/e-mail')
sleep(5)
login = browser.find_element(By.ID, value="TLoginBox")
login.click()
```

I am new to programming, so any help means a lot.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the error indicates, the element TLoginBox doesn't exist. What are you trying to get?

Comment: When u open the Website: there is a pinkish Email-Login Button. I want to click that

Answer (score 0):

The element cannot be found because it is inside another frame, try the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Chrome('F:/trzttrtz/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.t-online.de/themen/e-mail')
frame = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'TlgnBoxIfr')
browser.switch_to_frame(frame)
login = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value='TlogBtn')
login.click()
```

If you want to go back to the main frame use:

```
browser.switch_to().default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

The element with the text as *E-Mail Login* is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.t-online.de/themen/e-mail')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.TlgnBoxIfr")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.TlogBtn>span.mailicn>img"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.t-online.de/themen/e-mail')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='TlgnBoxIfr']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='TlogBtn']/span[@class='mailicn']/img"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: telekonLogin]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)